# Condition to check if python variable is present in Mongo DB field. If already exsists ignore oherwise push to DB

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mongodb, flask

```
for file in files:
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            templist = []
            ...
            string = ''.join([e[1] for e in sorted(license_info, key=lambda x:x[0])]) ## This is pushed to MongoDB in a field name ID.
            templist.append(string)
            currentdate = datetime.datetime.now().date()
            date = currentdate + relativedelta(years=1) ## This is pushed to MongoDB in a field name date.
            templist.append(str(date))
            df.loc[len(df)] = templist
if collection.count_documents({}) == 0: ## If the table is empty I have pushed the dataframe directly in DB.
   collection.insert_many(df.to_dict('records'))
else:
   ## Here is the help needed !!!
   If DB has some data I want to search the string value in the field "ID", if it is present then corresponding "Date" value will be printed, else push the Field ID and date coming from above loop in the DB. This is to avoid duplicacy of data in field "ID".
```

Example record format -

```
ObjectId('5f7ebd2e8827d15b764e9402'), 'ID': 'b0862b10-acd2-81e4-2991-086266236905', 'Date': '2021-10-08'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5f7ebd2e8827d15b764e9403'), 'ID': 'b0862b10-acd2-81e4-2991-086266236905', 'Date': '2021-10-08'}
```

In the above example value of ID's in both the records are same, this I have to avoid and search in DB first in ID section from string coming from python loop. If exsist print the corresponding Date, otherwise do-not insert that string as Field value in ID as it is already there in DB.
I am new to Mongo DB and wanted to do this in Python, suggest some thing...
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So just query mongoDB using the ID?

Comment: I am new to MongoDB, can you mention please some query code in python for same. It would be great help.

Comment: what about using "collection.find_one({"ID": your_id_string})" to search the string value in the field "ID" to see if it exits.

Comment: Thanks BOB it worked!!One more question in same series - if collection.find_one({"ID": your_id_string}): Then how to fetch the corresponding date in the date field inside if loop?? Please help!!

Comment: @RajatKumarSinha  For to check `ID` along with `Date` inside `if` -- `collection.find_one({"ID": your_id_string , "Date": your_date})`   ... But if you want corresponding date of result then you could probably do as `result = collection.find_one({"ID": your_id_string})` and then `corr_date = result['Date']`   --- you could go through basics of mongo+python  [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_getstarted.asp)